# JQuery templates or Microsoft DataView?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, microsoft-ajax

Greetings,

I'm confused about which client-side template engine is recommended by Microsoft.

Microsoft [announced the release of a jQuery templating engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/04/jquery-templates-data-link-and-globalization-accepted-as-official-jquery-plugins.aspx), while there's another templating engine created by microsoft, called [the DataView component](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2009/09/10/microsoft-ajax-4-preview-5-the-dataview-control.aspx) which will be shipped as a part of Microsoft Ajax 4.0 when it's released (it's still in the beta stage).

The two engines have major differences and approaches, which makes me confused because I find it strange that a company creates two products to handle one task.

So, what engine of the two do you recommend?

(The same thing can be said about the MS jQuery globalization plugin and the MS Ajax globalization extensions (Sys.CultureInfo, String.format, Number.format, etc), but this is another story)

Comment: This <a href="http://visitmix.com/Articles/Javascript-Libraries-and-ASPNET">important article</a> answers my question. One of the answers by Dave Ward says <i>I recommend using jQuery and its plugins for anything you’re starting today. If you need templating, use the jQuery Templating plugin until jQuery 1.5 is released</i>. I'm sad that these great Microsoft client side components are going to be deprecated.

Comment: Here's another important article about the subject http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/03/16/microsoft-jquery-and-templating.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using (or planning to use) jQuery, then using the jQuery templating engine makes total sense as it will be a familiar approach.

There's some good notes on the Pro's of it [here](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, I use both jQuery and MS Ajax/AjaxControlToolkit. In some areas I prefer the former and in others I prefer the latter. But what makes me confused, is why MS made two technologies.